# Is there a way to automatically log onto a Windows XP machine at specific time?

Tags: windows-xp, timer, cmd, authentication

How to set a specific logon time for a specific user on Windows XP?
For example, the computer is an "always on machine" and most of the time no one is logged on. I want to set a time for my user to log on, without someone actually having to be in front of the machine. I've tried a workaround with the built-in auto logon function (control userpassword2), but I still need a secure system as I'm not the only user, and would still want a password even if I was the only user.

I have searched for third party software, but to no avail. I've a good knowledge of batch and Python scripting and a little of Java, so any pointers with any of those would help.

Comment: What is the purpose of logging in to the system?  You can remote into the system and log in from a different system using RDP.

Answer (score 0):

How can it be "secure" if it logs you on without you being there? Surely it would be better for it to wait for you to type in a password (i.e. the login prompt)?

If you want a fast "startup" time, then you can lock the workstation (ctrl+alt+del to open the Task Manager and then click 'Lock'. This shows a dialog just like the login prompt, but when you enter your password you instantly continue your existing session). Or if you want to be more eco friendly, put your PC into Sleep mode, which most PCs will return from (again with an optional password prompt) in less than 5 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

One way I just thought of: Run a Vnc Server, and hack into an open source viewer program.  Then you can rig it with some code to pass keyboard commands back into the computer, maybe implement some screen scraping to make sure it only does it when appropriate.

But seriously, there has to be a better way.  Why are you trying to do this?